# When the Flink+Redisson runs abnormally and repeated retries, the Redis connections counts will continue to grow and eventually reach the upper limit

Tags: apache-flink

I encountered a problem in the process of integrating Flink and Redisson. When the task encounters abnormalities and keeps retries, it will cause the number of Redis Clients to increase volatility (sometimes the number increases, sometimes the number decreases, but the overall trend is growth). Even if I shutdown the Redisson Instance by overwriting the close function , the number of Redis-Clients cannot be prevented from continuing to grow, and eventually the number of Clients will reach the upper limit and an error will be thrown. Moreover, this situation only occurs in the Flink cluster operation mode, and the number of Redis-Clients will remain stable in the local mode. The test code is below. I wonder if you can provide specific reasons and solutions for this situation, thank you.

flink version:1.13.0
redisson version:3.16.1

```
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.SimpleStringSchema;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.TimeCharacteristic;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;

public class ExceptionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(new Configuration());
        env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);
        env.enableCheckpointing(1000 * 60);
        DataStream<String> mock = createDataStream(env);
        mock.keyBy(x -> new Random().nextInt(20))
                .process(new ExceptionTestFunction())
                .uid("batch-query-key-process")
                .filter(x->x!=null)
                .print();
        env.execute("Exception-Test");
    }

    private static DataStream<String> createDataStream(StreamExecutionEnvironment env) {
        String topic = "test_topic_xhb03";
        Properties test = new Properties();
        test.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "broker");
        test.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group");

        FlinkKafkaConsumer<String> consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer<String>(topic, new SimpleStringSchema(), test);
        consumer.setStartFromLatest();

        DataStream<String> source = env.addSource(consumer);
        return source;
    }
}


import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.flink.configuration.Configuration;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.KeyedProcessFunction;
import org.apache.flink.util.Collector;
import org.redisson.Redisson;
import org.redisson.api.RedissonRxClient;
import org.redisson.config.Config;

@Slf4j
public class ExceptionTestFunction extends KeyedProcessFunction<Integer, String, String> {
    private RedissonRxClient redisson;

    @Override
    public void close() {
        this.redisson.shutdown();
        log.info(String.format("Shut down redisson instance in close method, RedissonRxClient shutdown is %s", redisson.isShutdown()));

    }
   
    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) {
        String prefix = "redis://";
        Config config = new Config();
                        config.useSingleServer()
                                .setClientName("xhb-redisson-main")
                                .setTimeout(5000)
                                .setConnectTimeout(10000)
                                .setConnectionPoolSize(4)
                                .setConnectionMinimumIdleSize(2)
                                .setIdleConnectionTimeout(10000)
                                .setAddress("127.0.0.1:6379")
                                .setDatabase(0)
                                .setPassword(null);
        this.redisson = Redisson.create(config).rxJava();
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(String value, Context ctx, Collector<String> out) throws Exception {
        throw new NullPointerException("Null Pointer in ProcessElement");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified if the close() method is being called? Perhaps with an uncaught exception, it doesn't get called?

Comment: There is no doubt that the close() method has been called. In my test program, the only exception that will be thrown is NPE. Then, by observing the program log, you can find the log printed in the close method, indicating that the close() method has been called, but I don't know if there is a possibility that the close() method is not completely called for every exception